# HTML input array elements with numeric keys

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to have some html like this:

```
<input name="list_item[0][name]" />
<input name="list_item[1][name]" />
<input name="list_item[2][name]" />
```

When I view the raw source of my document, I see these correctly. But when I do inspect element in chrome or firefox, the numbers are incrementing by one! So I see:

```
<input name="list_item[1][name]" />
<input name="list_item[2][name]" />
<input name="list_item[3][name]" />
```

And when I inspect the submitted data, the keys start at 1, not 0 which is causing my code to misbehave:

```
'list_item' => 
    array
      1 => 
        array
          'name' => string 'title 1' (length=7)
      2 => 
        array
          'name' => string 'title 2' (length=7)
      3 => 
        array
          'name' => string '' (length=0)
```

Why is this happening? `O_o`

Comment: Any js doing that magic? What if you turn off js and try again?

Comment: Please answer so I can mod you up ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what exactly caused that, but seems like it was some js ;-)

Comment: Yar. It's pretty late and I should have recognized this. I just tried the raw html and it worked fine.